# Cant get json from my link with Volley in android studio

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

Here my code to parse json from my link http://192.168.1.9/androidwebservice/getdata.php in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String urlGetData = "http://192.168.1.9/androidwebservice/getdata.php";
    String url = "http://my-json-feed";
    String convertedResponse = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GetData(urlGetData);
    }

    private void GetData(String url) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LOOIVVVVV", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}
```

when i run the app with this [link](https://api.myjson.com/bins/jxwbo) , it works. but when i do it with my link http://192.168.1.9/androidwebservice/getdata.php it dont work.(This link i get data from database MySQl and parse to json) And when i check, it's the same.
Here my php file:

```
<?php
    $connect    = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sinhvien");
    mysqli_query($connect,"SET NAMES ");
    $query ="SELECT * from student";
    $data = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    class SinhVien{
        function SinhVien($id,$hoten,$namsinh,$diachi){
            $this->ID=$id;
            $this->HoTen=$hoten;
            $this->NamSinh=$namsinh;
            $this->DiaChi=$diachi;
        }
    }
    $mangSV=array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
      array_push($mangSV, new SinhVien($row['id'],$row['hoten'],$row['namsinh'],$row['diachi']));
    }
    echo json_encode($mangSV);
?>
```

Comment: could you please add the error-message

Comment: i have no error. just the json cant be show in my screen virtual